# Array out of Index

Tags: android, adapter

When RecyclerView is scrolled to the end it gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9 error . There are 10 links which provides images to the Adapter. Using android_image_urls.length also gives same error

```
public class MyHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder> {**//line 31**
public List<Notes> dataset= new ArrayList<>();
public Context context;
private final String android_image_urls[] = {//10 image urls
};
private final String note_title[] = {
        "Physics", "ElectroMagnetics", "DSA", "Electrical", "Electrical Machine", "Numerical Method"
        , "Digital Logic", "EDC", "ECT"};
private final String note_author[] = {"hari", "ram", "shyam", "binod", "ghanshyam", "BP", "RP", "NPA", "IB", "TS"};
private final String download[] = {"10", "11", "23", "54", "45", "34", "32", "56", "12", "12"};

public List<Notes> add() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        Notes notes = new Notes(android_image_urls[i], note_title[i], note_author[i], download[i]);
        dataset.add(notes);
        //Toast.makeText(Most_loved.this, String.valueOf(dataset.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return dataset;
}

public MyHorizontalAdapter(Context context, List<Notes> dataset) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public MyHorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(android_image_urls[position])
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery).fit().into(holder.randomImageView);**//line 79**
    holder.title.setText("Title: "+ note_title[position]);
    holder.author.setText("Author: " + note_author[position]);
    holder.downloads.setText("Downloads: " +download[position]);

}
```

Error:

```
06-25 21:23:46.032 8498-8498/com.example.zaraki.ioenote     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.zaraki.ioenote, PID: 8498
                                                                      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
                                                                          at com.example.zaraki.ioenote.RecyclerView.MyHorizontalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyHorizontalAdapter.java:79)
                                                                          at com.example.zaraki.ioenote.RecyclerView.MyHorizontalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyHorizontalAdapter.java:31)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:528)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1019)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(GridLayoutManager.java:361)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4057)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Whats your implementation of the getItemCount methode in your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Your `note_title` array contains only 9 entries, not 10. So the index 9 is invalid.

Comment: When I added an Entry it gave
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10. Thank You

Comment: Please post the complete error message (stack trace with line numbers).

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, the only time the indexing of an array is not in your control is in the method `onBindViewHolder`.

Make sure the `final int position` you're passing is less than 10. I suspect you might've called `array.length` at some point and forgot to subtract 1.

Comment: subract where ? I couldnt get you!

Comment: Do you call `onBindViewHolder` in any of your other code? You passed in a `position` that is out of bounds. Alternatively, you can use an if statement to make sure that `position < note_title.length`

Comment: Actually the horizontal recyclerview is part of a nested recycler view with vertical recycler view as parent recycler view. So the vertical recycler view also has an **onBindViewHolder** if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Let me try to reword this... Do you ever use the `onBindViewHolder` method? If you do, what do you put in for the position? Is that number greater than or equal to 10? If so, then you have to fix the part of your code where you use `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: The number is not greater than 10 anywhere. When I scroll past the last item it force stops. Before that all items are shown.

Comment: Just try wrapping your 3 `holder.xxx.setText()` lines in `if (position < note_title.length) { //code here }`.

Comment: Actually, wrap that whole method in the if statement.